# "viel" takes no declension as adverb

Tags: adjective, adverb, declension, interrogative

I know **viel** is declined when used as an adjective. My textbook says the word **viel** in the combination **wie viel** (how much/how many) takes no declension, but then it gives the following examples:

> **Wie viele** Leute sitzen draußen?
>
> Für **wie viele** Personen?

which seem a contradiction because an *-e* has been added for the plural.
What am I not getting?

Answer (score 4):

As you said, "viel" can be used for countable things ("many") as well as for not countable things ("much"). For countable things, "viel" is declined:

> Ich sehe viele Vögel. ("I see many birds.")
>
> Ich gebe vielen Vögeln Futter. ("I give food to many birds.")

For not countable things, there's no declension:

> Ich kaufe viel Futter. ("I buy much food.")

You can also use both cases in one sentence:

> Ich gebe vielen Vögeln viel Futter. ("I give much food to many birds.")

The same principle holds for questions:

> Wie viele Vögel siehst Du? ("How many birds do you see?")
>
> Wie viel Futter brauchst Du für die vielen Vögel? ("How much food do you need for the many birds?")

Comment: Maybe change your example "*Ich gebe vielen Vögeln viel Futter*" to "*Ich gebe den Vögeln viel Futter*" to avoid the ambiguity that is created by the two forms of *viel*.

Comment: @infinitezero ... but it's confusing, since it's introduced with "for not countable things". I'd denote separate paragraphs to countable/non countable/both/questions to escalate it slowly enough that learners don't get confused.

Comment: @infinitezero yes

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck, then is my book wrong when saying wie viel   is  not declined or is it that perhaps plural is not considered a declension?. viel is an adverd there ,right? Could you add more examples of  "wie viel" declined other than wie viel and wie viele?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver According to the Duden, there's [an adverb "viel"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_sehr_besonders_wesentlich) and [a pronoun or numeral "viel"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/viel_zahlreich_vielerlei). I'd guess that maybe with not countable things you use the adverb and with countable things the numeral? But that's beyond my knowledge of the technicalities of the German language.